# Running MPI programs with multiple processes with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, gcc, mpi, codeblocks

I am new to MPI and trying to run 'hello world' program. Here is my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int mynode, totalnodes;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode);
    cout << "Hello world from process " << mynode;
    cout << " of " << totalnodes << endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The output is just

Hello world from process 0 of 1

I have multi-core CPU and I think there should be at least 4 processes running. So Output should be:

Hello world from process 0 of 4
   Hello world from process 1 of 4
   Hello world from process 2 of 4
   Hello world from process 3 of 4

or something similar. Can anyone comment what did I miss in the program or compile command? By the way I am running on Windows, MSMPI, gcc compiler on Code::Blocks IDE. Thanks.

Comment: How are you running the program? What's the full command line with mpirun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me.

I copy pasted your code into mpi_app.cpp. mpicxx a compiler wrapper script provided by MPI implementers that takes care of includes and libs. mpirun is a wrapper script for launching mpi programs that is also provided by MPI implementers. The MPI implementation I'm using is mpich2.

```
$ mpicxx -O0 -o mpi_app mpi_app.cpp
$ mpirun -n 4 ./mpi_app
Hello world from procHello world from process 2 Hello world from process Hello world from process 0 oess 1 of 4
of 4
3 of 4
f 4
```

Note: "f 4" is not a copy paste error. When multiple processes are writing to stdout you should expect garbled or interspersed messages.

It sounds like you are getting it to compile, but if not, it looks like on Windows you have to manually add the include and lib: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/risman/archive/2009/01/04/ms-mpi-with-visual-studio-2008.aspx

From that same link, it looks like the command on a Windows command line is:

```
mpiexec –n 10 MyMPIProject.exe
```

To get this to run within code::blocks you need to tell code::blocks to run the command just like above. From the blog post linked below, it looks like code::blocks uses a 'cb_console_runner.exe' to run compiled programs. This blog post has a modified version of that program that will accept a -mpi flag telling it where mpiexec is.

http://www.blog.kubiak.co.uk/post/44

Setting the -mpi flag:

"Argument this must be define in Codeblocks menu in Project -> Set programs’ arguments?

```
-mpi <path to mpiexec> -n <number of processes>
```

example:

```
-mpi C:/Progra~1/MPICH2/bin/mpiexec -n 8
```

"

Comment: I did not use wrapper mpiexec.exe . I used code::blocks ide, and just pointed at directories. files to include. However I am not getting desired output (that you got).

Comment: So are you actually running the program from within code::blocks somehow? If that's the case, somewhere in the code::blocks settings there should be a way to change what code::blocks runs. code::blocks is just handing off, not doing anything special. Whether through an IDE or on the command line, you want the executable to be mpiexec with the rest as arguments. It might be worthwhile to try this on the command line at least once.

Comment: I did what you said in link and your approach works! Thanks! However how I can do this in code::blocks? I mean I didn't find anything to use wrapper mpiexec.exe to run the program. Any comments?

Comment: Answer edited with a link on how to do that. Caveat: I have no direct experience with code::blocks, just MPI

Comment: That blog post is a bit hard to read, but now that I look again, it seems like he actually posted a modified cb_console_runner.exe and you would need that to use the -mpi flag.

Comment: According to your comment and the blog's info, I used option `projects->set program's arguments...->` then `-mpi "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\mpiexec.exe" -n 4`. However the program (console application) still doesn't run as expected.

Comment: Did you try the modified cb_console_runner.exe posted on the blog? From what I saw searching, the base cb_console_runner.exe simply can't be configured to run the mpi wrapper.

Comment: The cb_console_runner.zip file on the blog has a "cb_console_runner_windows/mpi/cb_console_runner.exe" that looks promising, although I don't have a Windows machine to try it. That one should be used to replace the original (but save the original!).

Comment: I didn't quite get that. Where is `cb_console_runner.exe` and how to modify that? Will you explain in bit detail? I also tried finding this on blog post you indicated http://www.blog.kubiak.co.uk/post/44 but couldn't get exactly.

Comment: There's a link at the bottom to a file, 'cb_console_runner.zip'. It has source code and a binary for a patched cb_consoler_runner.exe that can accept the '-mpi' flag. As for where that file is on your computer, it depends on where you have code::blocks installed. It is likely somewhere in Program Files. You could just file search that directory.

Comment: There you go! Thanks a lot!