# Fatal error in MPI_Send: Invalid rank, error stack

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mpi

I am writing code with mpi in c++, and I have done this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#define NMAX 100
#define NTIMES 10
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int rank, size, i, n, lmax;
double time_start, time, bandwidth, max, a[NMAX];
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
time_start = MPI_Wtime();
n = 0;
max = 0.0;
lmax = 0;
while(n<=NMAX){
  time_start = MPI_Wtime();
  for(i = 0; i<NTIMES; i++){
     if(rank==0){
        MPI_Send(a, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(a, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     }
     if(rank==1){
        MPI_Recv(a, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(a, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     }
  }
  time = (MPI_Wtime()-time_start)/(2*NTIMES);
  bandwidth = (sizeof(double)*n*1.0/(1024*1024*time));
  if(max<bandwidth){
     max = bandwidth;
     lmax = sizeof(double)*n;
  }
  if(rank==0)
     if(n==0) printf("latency = %lf seconds\n", time);
     else printf("%d bytes, bandwidth = %lf Mb/s\n", (int)sizeof(double)*n, bandwidth);
  if(n==0) n = 1;
  else n = 2*n;
  }
  if(rank==0) printf("max bandwidth = %lf Mb/s length = %d bytes\n", max, lmax);
  MPI_Finalize();
   }
```

It shows no errors, but when i am trying to run the code, this what i have..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl0HF.png

Maybe someone knows hov can i fix it?

Comment: It seems you have to run your code using 2 processes. How did you run your code?

Comment: I am using codeblocks, so just by "build and run".

Comment: @Justyna You cannot "just run" an MPI program. You need to use an MPI launcher (mpiexec, mpirun, aprun, etc.). Check the documentation of your MPI implementation (such as OpenMPI, MPICH, Intel MPI, Cray MPI, ...).

Comment: @Daniel Langr i have MPICH2, but i do not know how to run this code using 2 processes

Comment: @Justyna Then read MPICH2 documentation.

Comment: Related question: [Setting Code Block to run MPICH2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5141042/580083).

Comment: The related question doesn't actually deal with running an MPI project under Code::Blocks. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24356286/1374437) does.

Comment: What's happening is that when your simply run an MPI executable, it does the so-called *singleton MPI_INIT* and behaves as a 1-rank MPI job, i.e., as if launched with `mpiexec -n 1 <executable>`. You need to tell Code::Blocks to not run the executable directly but rather run it through `mpiexec`.